# combine/merge php functions

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to insert the following code into PHP, but I'm not sure of the correct syntax.

```
echo SPEC($GLOBALS['_LANG']['Pay Now with PayPal'])
```

It needs to go in place of the 'Pay Now with PayPal' that already exists there.

```
'7' => array('name' => 'Display Name', 'type' => 'text', 'fieldname' => 'gateway_paypal_name', 'default' => 'Pay Now with PayPal'),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'7' => array('name' => 'Display Name', 'type' => 'text', 'fieldname' => 'gateway_paypal_name', 'default' => SPEC($GLOBALS['_LANG']['Pay Now with PayPal'])),
```